# Accessing individual bits in an integer, why does this require use of >>?

Tags: java

I'm reading source code from a processor emulator written in Java, and the line below makes use of the `>>` operator to read the value of certain individual bits stored within a variable.

```
        //Bits 3-5 of IR denote addressing mode of instruction
        int irAddressMode = (ir >> 2) & 0x07; 
        //Bits 6-7 of IR denote operation mode of instruction
        int irOpMode = ir & 0x03;
```

I understand the second line, where `irOpMode` is determined. By ANDing the value held in `ir` with `0x03` we are left solely with the value of bits 6-7 in the bit pattern (working in little-endian).

However I don't understand the need for the `>>` operator in the first line, why is it first required to do `(ir >> 2)` before ANDing, to find the value of bits 3-5 in the `ir` variable?

Comment: It's much like dividing the number by 4 (for unsigned values). There is any other way to select specific bits, this is the most efficient. e.g. you can do `int irAddressMode = ir / 4 % 8;` if `ir` is unsigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not required to get the bits, but to get the IR addressing mode that is saved in the first variable. You could AND with 0x1C to just get the bits, but then the value would be too large. Assuming that the addressing mode is 1 you would get the value 4 (binary 100). The shift operation fixes that.

Comment: Oh I see, so you're shifting to the left so that you get values between 1-7, rather than values between 16-28?

Comment: Well, **0**-7, unless you know that binary 000 will never occur as an address mode...